# Inserir PHP em div com Jquery (.html)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Eu tenho uma `div` que vai receber o conteúdo, tenho um menu vertical, que vai definir o conteúdo que o fulano vai ver. O problema está que ele faz o `.load()` do arquivo, mas ele carrega até onde aparece

Tentei pelo `.html()`, e colocar um `include` `.php`, ele até faz, mas dá o mesmo problema. Não lê as informações depois do PHP. Tentei escrever a página dentro do `.html()`, mas também não funciona, fiz as correções de aspas duplas com barra invertida (\") e não funcionou.

Nos bibliotecas oficiais não consegui uma resposta se o caso for com Banco de Dados e PHP. mas não consigo compreender, por que não funciona.

Meu código é um pouco grande, pois são vários links e os conteúdos são extensos, fiz um exemplo reduzido, porque acho que o problema é de conceito, não de sintaxe.

- O problema não está no PHP e MySQL, porque se eu abro a página somente, fora do jQuery, funciona tranquila, pega todos os dados.
- O banco jQuery e a conexão com MySQL já estão sendo feitas e funcionam, não coloquei para não encher de código inútil.

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#link1").click(function() {
$("#conteudo").html("Aqui vai o conteúdo do Link 1, via HTML mesmo, pois não tem PHP.. Esse aqui funciona normalmente!");
});
$("#link2").click(function() {
$("#conteudo").load('link2.php');
});
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
  <a href="#link1" id="link1">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#link2" id="link2">Link 2</a>

  <div id="conteudo">Este conteúdo é para ser alterado, conforme o usuário vá clicando no link... O link 1 funciona normal, pois não tem php, o link 2 funciona até aparecer o PHP...</div>
```

O PHP (link2.php)

```
  <?php
$query = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dados;");
while($linha = @mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
<p><?php echo $linha['nome']. " - ". $linha['sobrenome']; ?> 
<a href="imagens/foto.jpg">Veja a foto</a>
</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: No link2.php não está abrindo a base de dados, cade a conexão???, e não utilize @ para omitir os erros retire isso, não está carregando nada porque não tem conexão ativa nos trechos de código

Comment: Eu já fiz a conexão em um require na página que vai incluir... Não coloquei no código, porque achei que seria besteira... Eu realmente nem sei porque coloquei esse @.. vou retirá-lo para ver o que acontece..

Comment: Por favor, coloque toda a página que podemos nos atentar o que está realmente acontecendo ... !!! @ significa omissão de erros ... deu um erro não aparece !!! (usar em casos bem definidos)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **TL;DR** - Inclua os arquivos php que definem a conexão em `link2.php`. O  [`.load()`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) do jQuery só irá funcionar quando você puder fazer uma requisição direta para `link2.php` e receber o fragmento html desejado.

Você está confundindo duas coisas. A interpretação de comandos PHP *server-side* (`include`)  com funcionalidades ajax *client-side*.

O método `load`do jQuery espera que o `link2.php` retorne uma página ou fragmento html. No caso o `link2.php` sozinho não produz nada, apenas falha silenciosamente (`@`) devido a falta de uma conexão ativa.

```
Request 1 -> Pagina 1 -> Request 2 -> link2.php (sem conexão) = Falha silenciosa
```

O que você precisa fazer é criar uma página `link2.php` que funcione sozinha (ou seja, retorne resultados quando um *request* for feito diretamente pelo navegador). Para isso você deve incluir código para conectar no banco e tudo o que for necessário para imprimir os resultados.

Veja que essa funcionalidade é bem diferente de um `require` ou `include`; esses fazem tudo do lado do servidor:

```
Request 1 -> 
    Pagina 1, cria conexões etc
        include 'link2.php'
            usa conexão "definida" na página 1
<- Servidor interpreta o conjunto e navegador recebe uma resposta HTML unificada
```

Nesse caso não existe um segundo *request*, o conteúdo de `link2.php` é interpretado junto com o conteúdo da página atual pelo servidor como se fosse mais um pedaço de código PHP no corpo da página. O navegador não tem ciência de que esses são dois arquivos separados.

Comment: Interessante Anthony.. Eu achei que assim eu estaria duplicando as conexões, mas o que me chamou a atenção é sobre um erro conceitual mesmo que estou cometendo.. vou tentar dessa forma.. Aviso aqui o resultado...

Comment: Anthony... Você estava coberto de razão, acho que entendeu exatamente qual era minha dúvida e onde eu estava errando. Foi simplesmente colocar um require da conexão com o Banco de Dados.. que tudo deu certo... Eu estava com o conceito errado.. Não tinha esquecido da conexão, achei que estaria duplicando.. Aprendi muito neste tópico, agradeço imensamente a ajuda.

Comment: Sem problemas Luther, essa é uma confusão clássica, a divisão entre o que é feito no servidor e o que é feito no cliente vai se tornando mais clara com o tempo. Não se esqueça de seguir as dicas do colega Fúlvio e substituir a extensão MySQL por MySQLi ou PDO, é bem melhor fazer isso agora do que no futuro quando sua base de código estiver enorme.

Answer (score 2):

Tente usar um aplicativo como o firebug para [debugar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W4jXAaEMp2M) a transação e verificar se está recebendo os dados corretamente durante a requisição feita com o jQuery.

**Tente o exemplo a seguir:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#link2").on('click', function(){
      $.get("link2.php", function( data ) {
        $('#conteudo').html(data);
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Olá hamboldt, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Obrigado pela sua contribuição. Um ponto de atenção é que esse seria um comentário e não uma resposta (apesar de entender a questão da falta de reputação, estou contribuindo com um voto). Já que você postou uma resposta não seria interessante ampliá-la com possíveis razões para o método `load` estar falhando? (Por exemplo `data` realmente contém um fragmento html que o `callback` do `load` está descartando, ou `data` não está retornando nada devido a falta de um parâmetro qualquer, ou ainda `data` está retornando as tags `php` sem interpretá-las).

Comment: Ele faz a mesma coisa que o Include e que o .load(), puxa o que está em HTML, mas não o que está em PHP... depois que aparece <?php no código da página link2.php ele já não mostra nada..

Comment: user, estou desconfiado que você tem algum erro server side na geração das linhas. Tente um `console.log(data)` dentro do `callback`. O html é o mesmo do que se navegar diretamente para `link2.php`?

Comment: Não... Anthony, se eu abro o Link2.php somente, não dá porque ele não tem as conexões.. mas se eu dou um include, fora do Jquery, tudo funciona na mais perfeita harmonia...

Comment: Eis o problema, o request ajax faz exatamente a mesma coisa do que se você fizesse um request direto no navegador.

Comment: É mas então porque não dá certo no Jquery? e no Html, tudo funciona?

Comment: Porque `include` é diferente de ajax. O primeiro é inteiramente *server-side*, ele coloca o conteúdo do arquivo no contexto atual (com as conexões) antes de fazer a query, o outro faz um *request* que bate no servidor; nesse caso ele tenta executar a query e falha silenciosamente (por causa do `@`) devido a conexão não estar configurada.

Comment: Ah, entendi o que você quis dizer.. Vou fazer os testes aqui, já, aviso o que deu..

Comment: Com esse sistema que o Hambolt mandou, deu esse aviso... Ao retirar os @... 

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /home/lutpad/rodadesamba.net/samba/perfil/enviadas.php on line 4

Comment: Hamboldt, obrigado pela ajuda. Irei aprender a usar o Firebug, agradeço pela dica.

Answer (score 2):

```
    //menu.php
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Load(View){
            $("#carregar").html('Carregando ...');
            $("#carregar").load(View);
        };
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $("#a1").click(function(e) {
               Load('page1.php'); 
            });
            $("#a2").click(function(e) {
                Load('page2.php'); 
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="javascript:" id="a1">Abrir Tela 1</a>
            <a href="javascript:" id="a2">Abrir Tela 2</a>
        </div>
        <div id="carregar"></div>
    </body>
    </html>

    //page1.php
    <h1>Pagina Link 1</h1>

    //page2.php
    <h1>Pagina Link 2</h1>
<?php
    $conexao = new PDO("mysql:dbname=generics;host=localhost", "root", "senha");
    $tables  = $conexao->prepare("show tables");
    $tables->execute();
    print_r($tables->fetchAll());
?>
```

A página menu chama a page1.php e a page2.php sendo que a page2.php tem uma conexão com o banco de dados com a classe PDO, cuidado em colocar @, porque, omite erros e a classe mysql já é obsoleta nas novas versões do PHP, logo serão retiradas, trabalhe com mysqli ou PDO (PDO acredito ser melhor pela padronização de codificação, servindo a mesma para diversões tipos de bancos) ...

Comment: Fúlvio, dessa forma eu não estaria chamando a conexão duas vezes? Porque eu tenho o require de conexão lá em cima.. E funciona normal se ele não estiver dentro do Jquery... De qualquer forma vou tentar esse formato, assim que fizer te digo a resposta..

Comment: Inclusive lá em cima da onde? então, Não ... são processos separados, ou chamadas distintas ... o load do jquery é um processo Ajax que roda em um momento diferente daquilo ... então você deve passar a conexão para cada trecho de página que vão ser carregadas no evento do load do jquery

Comment: Compreendi, e não poderia fazer de uma forma trivial. Chamando um novo require da conexão, nessa página link2.php? 
Quando eu disse lá em cima, quis dizer primeira linha da página que recebe o Jquery.

Pra ser sincero, essa parte do PDO me confundiu, porque nunca nem tinha visto, não estudei sobre ele em momento algum..

Comment: Seguinte, esquece o PDO, na sua página link2.php coloque a require ou include da sua conexão e faça o teste e relate a nós o que aconteceu ... ????

Comment: Fúlvio, era simples mesmo.. Era um erro de conceito.. Eu não pensei na possibilidade de fazer uma conexão.. Inexperiência minha, eu acreditei que com aquela conexão já estaria apto para resgatar dados do MySQL. Foi somente colocar um um include da minha conexão, e pronto! Agora o que me confundiu mesmo, foi essa questão do PDO, vou buscar mais informações para entendê-la..  Muito Obrigado Fúlvio...  Uma pena que não posso dar reputação!

Comment: O intuito é crescimento não somente pontos, fique tranquilo, todo material de PDO tem no proprio php.net nesse link: http://br2.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php ou também Mysqli que é somente para mysql no link: http://br2.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php
Boa sorte !!!